# Error in php code

Tags: php, functions

I was following the Book building wordpress theme from scratch.  An options page is created through this method in the wordpress admin panel .  There is an error present due to which nothing appears inside it.

Firstly this is added to the **functions.php** of WordPress:

```
<?php require_once('theme-options.php'); ?>
```

Secondly **theme-options.php** is created which contains this:

```
<?php 
// create custom plugin settings menu
 add_action('admin_menu', 'director_create_menu');
 function director_create_menu() {

 //create new submenu
 add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'Director Theme Options', 
 'Director Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, 
 'wptuts_landing_settings_page');

 //call register settings function
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'director_register_settings' );
 } 
 function director_register_settings() {
  //register our settings
  register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_facebook' );
  register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_twitter' );
  register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_rss' );
  register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_logo' );
  register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_analytics' );
  }
  function director_settings_page() {
  ?>

 <div class="wrap">
 <h2>Director Theme Settings</h2>

  <form id="landingOptions" method="post" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields( 'director-settings-group' ); ?>
  <table class="form-table">

  <tr valign="top">
  <th scope="row">Logo:</th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="director_logo" value="<?php print get_option('director_logo'); ?>"      /> 
    <br/>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr valign="top">
  <th scope="row">Facebook Link:</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="director_facebook" 
  value="<?php print get_option('director_facebook'); 
  ?>" />
  </td>
  </tr>

 <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row">Twitter Link:</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="director_twitter" value="<?php print get_option('director_twitter'); ?>" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Display RSS Icon:</th>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="director_rss" <?php 
  if(get_option('director_rss') == true){ print 
   "checked"; } ?> />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Google Analytics Code:</th>
    <td>
      <textarea name="director_analytics"><?php print 
  get_option('director_analytics'); ?></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>

 <p class="submit">
   <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
 </p>

 </form>
</div>
```

The director options page is created however there is nothing inside it.

The page should show up like this:[image]
However the page is like this :
[image]
 Could you please tell me the problem and a fix to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no WordPress error (as you can see due to the page being completely loaded, see the WordPress footer, for instance) — it is a *user* error.

In the `add_submenu_page` call, you specified the function `wptuts_landing_settings_page`, while your actual function is called `director_settings_page`.